# How to secure api endpoints with token authentication

Tags: rest, validation, security, authentication, token

I have a backend server for my application communicating through REST api
User authentication is handled via JSON Web Token (JWT) - token signed by the server contains username

Let's say that an user created a Reservation with id 5 and has the privilage to delete it.
He would do so by sending a DELETE request to:

```
api.address/reservations/5
```

And that's a valid request. But some can try to delete any other reservation by simply sending a DELETE request with another id signed with a valid token.

What is the best approach to validate user privilages at the server side? So far  I came with these three solutions, but any of those doesn't feel right

1. Check through database every time for privilages check (possibly time consuming)
2. Containing all resource privilages in the user token (the tokens might get absurdly big)
3. Allowing only signed applications to access rest api (possible that key will be forged. Is there a 100% secure way to do that?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to store the username or user id (from the token) together with the reservation in for example the `creator` field. Then in your DELETE method, check that the user executing the request (again from the token) is the creator.

If so, delete the reservation and return `204 No content`. If not, return `403 Forbidden`.